# MarketingCloudSDKFoundation setupCoredataWithAppID:andAccessToken:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to write a react native bridge for marketing cloud sdk
using [this article](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/apple.html)
and have been nearly successful in initialising the push manager but once the code exits the function block it crashes with this error:

> MarketingCloudSDKFoundation setupCoredataWithAppID:andAccessToken:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Why do I get this error? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add the -ObjC to your target’s Other Linker Flags build settings.

Per the link you listed above, see Section 3, bullet #6.
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/apple.html

Comment: I have done that , if I would have not added the -ObjC flag it would not build. This is something which is happening once the app configures the sdk and gets the device token.

Comment: Can you post a snippet of when/where/how you are configuring the sdk? Are you attempting to configure it more than once?

Comment: any other solution besides adding -ObjC flag? becuase in my case I'm unable to add this flag since it creates duplicate symbols with other frameworks in project?

Comment: I was thinking on adding `-force_load` flag only on specific project but i'm I doubt it's even possible to apply to a .framework and not a static library. any help would be appreciated